# Strictly convex function on bounded interval is uniformly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

If a function $f$ is strictly convex and decreasing on $(0,\infty)$, is it possible to get a uniform bound on "how convex" it is on bounded intervals?  More precisely, for a bounded interval $(0,K]$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$ can we say that there is a constant $\delta > 0$ such that if $x,y \in (0,K]$ and $|x-y| > \varepsilon$ then $$f\left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right) \le \frac 12 (f(x)+f(y)) - \delta$$  It seems like we should be able to using the fact that $f'$ is bounded from above and the inequality $f(a) > f(b) + f'(b)(a-b)$, but I haven't been able to get anywhere with this approach.